# I want to create a wpf application which will remove the red eye from the image

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-3.0

I want to develop a WPF application. Now what i want is with that wpf application can i able to remove the red eye in the image or i have to use any other third party tool for that. any suggestions plz.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to this question is beyond the scope of what Stackoverflow can realistically be expected to provide...however I would suggest that you download the code for Paint.NET and have a look at what they do in this regard.